# firebase cloud function Retrieve data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

when I try to run this function it says:

> Error: Forbidden
>
> Your client does not have permission to get URL /tdata from this server.

My URL is `https://us-central1-*****.cloudfunctions.net/sdata`

Code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
 exports.tdata = functions.database.ref('/journey/kanpur-allahabad/seat').onWrite(event => {
    const num = event.data.val()
    
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 exports.tdata = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("/journey/kanpur-allahabad/seat");
   ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  }, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declared a function that is triggered by data that is written to the database. You can't invoke that function through a URL, which only applies to HTTP-triggered functions.

If you're looking to test a database-triggered function locally, you can [trigger it through the Cloud Functions shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_realtime_database_functions).

Comment: thanks for your  opinion  and i solved it buy using admin sdk. the code is   exports.tdata= functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("/journey/kanpur-allahabad/seat");
   ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
   
  
 
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
  });